What's wrong with my lamination?
When I roll my croissant dough it after enclosing the butter in it, the butter is visibly exposed at the edges, almost like there's not enough dough to cover it.
I'm trying to follow (as closely as possible) the technique demonstrated in this video by Jimmy Griffin, including slicing the folded ends of the dough after each fold, so that it's open at the sides. As in the video, I'm starting with my dough at ~3°C and butter at ~9°C. After that I'm keeping the dough around 9-12°C while working on it.
The croissants come out of the oven looking nice and flaky on the outside, but the interior is rather bready, and it certainly doesn't have that lovely honeycomb structure that I've seen photos of!
Where might I be going wrong here?





That looks like perfectly fine lamination to me...

@Marti Thanks, that's nice to hear! The crumb cross section looks a far cry from the light, airy ones I've seen (e.g., here) and I've not seen the butter splurging out of the dough like this anywhere I've looked, so I figured I must be doing something wrong… Should I just discard the end bits and not worry about it?

I'm wondering if these are just underproofed. I see clean separation between the layers, the crumb is just a little uneven and dense in places.
